# Sub queries with SOLR

Tags: solr

I am trying to use subquery in SOLR (like SQL), is there a way to implement this using SOLR? to use output of one query as input to another one.

Basically want to get set of records (lets say top 300) from solr then apply some filter on the results returned.

Is there any way to implement it in SOLR?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: What kind of filter? Do you have an example of exactly what you want to do?

Comment: first query solr for set of results based on some field and then apply the filters on the returned results, not the other way around that is apply all the filters and then get set of results
ex: query solr based on id:1000*, then apply the filter as sort=score desc

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. Filter queries are specifically targeted for that. Say, if a query with q=the returns you 3000 docs, you can further refine these by supplying fq=lang:en and get top 300 of the documents in English matching 'the'.

Comment: Correct, but the way i want is first query solr for set of results based on some field and then apply the filters on the returned results, not the other way around that is apply all the filters and then get set of results 
ex: query solr based on id:1000*, then apply the filter as sort=score desc

Comment: sort is not a filter, it is sorting. What are you trying to do is already like this: Solr will hit certain docs, sort by score and take a cut of top docs.

Comment: Correct but i want in other way around take a cut of top results and then sort.

Comment: @Sibasishpalo do you basically need two field sort?

Comment: not exactly, what exactly i want is first search, then whatever results i am getting take the top 20 then apply the sorting.

Comment: @Sibasishpalo ok. May be you can expand a little on what you are solving with this? Because there might be another approach. Otherwise, my best guess is to find stuff with solr, then perform resorting in your client code.